# install4j: adding shortcut/icon to metro desktop

Tags: windows-8, installation, install4j

I have successfully created desktop shortcut for my application (windows 8) but they show up on  windows desktop (non-metro).

I would also like to have a shortcut on the metro desktop.  Is it possible to do this within install4j add actions?  And if not, how can I do it with a script and install4j?

Thank you,.

Comment: You want your application to become a metro application? That is not possible with Java.

Comment: Not a metro app.  But a shortcut on the metro tiles.  All new apps (that are not metro) are doing this.  other installers do it too.  I am not sure how (there must be registry or script or something?)  For example, outlook is not a metro app but it has a shortcut.  I see other programs we well with other installers.  You click the shortcut and it brings up the windows desktop.  It is truly just a shortcut on the tiles.  But since windows 8 is here (as much as we love or hate it), we need to put our shortcut there.  I am not sure how to modify registry or what script..

Comment: It might be helpful if i give a little more info -- right now with my app installed, i can search for it on the metro screen (as you can search for control panel and other W7 features).  if i right click and "pin to desktop" then it becomes a shortcut on the metro.  This is what we are looking to do.  How do we "pin to desktop" (or create a whole new shortcut -- the more the merrier)

Comment: The "program group" part of the old start menu is now part of the metro screen. The "Create program group" action in install4j will add entries to it.